# Is my code correct for this space centered approximation

Tags: matlab, math

I am supposed to find the number of timesteps i.e the number of steps taken but my answer is incorrect any inputs on my code will be a major help thanks.Also has the advection equation  with the center spaced method used correctly ?
The program is matlab

```
N=200;
x=linspace(-10,10,N);
dx=x(2)-x(1);
c=-0.9;
t=0;
dt=0.2;
timestep=0;
f=@(x)exp(-5*x.^2);
y=f(x)';
figure(1),plot(x,y)
title(['Current time=',num2str(t)])
drawnow
```

using centered space (this where i think  am wrong)

```
A=eye(N)-(c*(dx/dt))*((diag(ones(N-1,1),1)-diag(ones(N-1,1),-1))/(2*dx));

%time ends when y goes to 0.01

while abs(y(end))<0.001 && abs(y(1))<0.001
y=A*y;
t=t+dt;
timestep=timestep+1;
figure(1),cla
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x,f(x-c*t),'r')
title(['Current time=',num2str(t)])
drawnow
end
```

Comment: What language is this? Is this MATLAB?

Comment: yes its is matlab sry

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of Numerical Instability, thus, any small error of your each step will exponentially grow to infinity.

The PDE you are simulating is [1D Convection Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6dTP.png). The Finite-Difference scheme you are using is FTCS for Forward-time-Centered-Space (i.e. you use the next time and current time to evaluate difference of time, and use left and right space to evaluate difference of space). **FTCS is always unstable when solving Convection Equations.**

If you want to get stable solutions, for `c<0` conditions, you can try **FTFS**, (use current space and right space rather than left and right). Thus your Matrix A should be like:

```matlab
A=eye(N)-(c*(dt/dx))*((diag(ones(N-1,1),1)-diag(ones(N,1),0)));
```

(If this is not the equation you are doing with, just change into what you are to use)

Also, to make FTFS stable, you have to ensure: `abs(c*dt/dx)<1` is true. Change dt and dx if it is not true.

Seemingly if c>0， you have to use FTBS for Forward-time-Backward-Space.

For more reference, you can access to any books about solving PDE numerically.

Hopes to help.

Comment: *FTCS is always unstable when solving Diffusion Equations.*....wrong.. `D delta t/ delta x^2 < 1/2` is stable.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should be Convection Equations, It is a 1st-order difference in space.

Comment: my question ask the following solve using the centered in space approximation so how do i go abt it ?

Comment: centerd in space is still FTCS ?

Comment: well, if your "centered in space" means y'->(y(x+dx)-y(x-dx))/(2*dx), It just wont work  here. FTFS is y'->(y(x+dx)-y(x))/(dx), you can get the difference.